# Views.py processing the form data

Tags: html, django

My form.html

```
      {{ form_field(task_form['execution_time']) }}
  <input type="text" name="admin_time">
```

views.py

```
    class CreateTaskView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyStaffUserRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
model = Task
form_class = TaskForm
template_name = 'tasks/form.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(CreateTaskView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['task_form'] = ctx.get('form')
        ctx['action'] = 'Add'
        ctx['cancel_url'] = reverse('tasks.list')
    return ctx

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save(self.request.user)

    messages.success(self.request, _('Your task has been created.'))
    return redirect('tasks.list')_url'] = reverse('tasks.list')
    return ctx
```

When processing the form if admin_time has a value, then execution_time should be equal to admin_time.

How can I bring that about?
I want something like this- but it throws eror

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(CreateTaskView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['task_form'] = ctx.get('form')
    if self.admin_time.is_valid():
        task.execution_time=self.admin_time
    else:
        ctx['action'] = 'Add'
        ctx['cancel_url'] = reverse('tasks.list')
    return ctx
```

Comment: What I basically want to do is:
if there's a value for the field admin_time, then execution_time should be admin_time, and this should be added during processing the form.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`CreateView.get_context_data` used to send additional context to your template (or override exist one) and it yields only when you have to render empty values `request.GET`

You can receive data on `request.POST`, so it yields methods in order (main of them) `dispatch` -> `post` -> `form_valid` or `form_invalid` -> redirect to success url. You can see there is no `get_context_data` so remove that weird code from `get_context_data`:

```
if self.admin_time.is_valid():
    task.execution_time=self.admin_time
else:
```

I can see you override `form_valid` so if it runs - form already is valid and you can get "cleaned data" from it if you want perform some additional validation, put following code **before** `form.save()`:

```
admin_time = form.cleaned_data['admin_time']

#  check if it is not empty
if admin_time:
    self.execution_time = admin_time
```

And you should not do this `return ctx` in your `form_valid`, because it never reach here after first return.

I also recommend you look at  `CreateView` class implementation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview and Django tutorials and docs if you want understand what you are doing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/ there ~ 6 tutorials, **read** and **try** it all and http://www.checkio.org/ for **learning python**. Because here we mainly don't loyal for **such** questions.